# No irq handler for vector (irq -1)

Tags: centos, irq

I recently installed Centos 6.5, however, I am constantly flooded by messages like:

```
Message from syslogd@localhost at May 18 15:38:34 ...
kernel:do_IRQ: 0.123 No irq handler for vector (irq -1)
```

I have tried multiple ways to solve, including:
`service irqbalance stop`, which resulted in "Failed", `chkconfig irqbalance off` and, most recently, even `yum remove irqbalance`, none of them solved the problem. What can I do?

Edit: I tried centosplus kernel now, the problem remains.